# What are the static ip addresses for SendGrid Incoming Parse WebHook servers?

Tags: sendgrid

I have a webserver endpoint for SendGrid Incoming Parse Webhook callback and would like to lock it down to the SendGrid server IP's.

What are the static ip addresses for SendGrid Incoming Parse WebHook servers?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any lookup for those IPs. Additionally Sendgrid could change them at any time which would break your setup. If you are trying to prevent random people and/or bots from messing with your endpoint(s) check out this solution: [SendGrid event notification authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55727577/sendgrid-event-notification-authentication/55819875#55819875)

Comment: Well if they do change the ip at least there should be a safe IP range to expect receiving the webhooks from and be able to allow inbound traffic to our machine. Of course then authentication is also needed but it comes after that.